# Promise not rejecting correctly in Jest test

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs

I am trying to test a `console.error` output when a promise rejects using Jest. I am finding that the promise seems to be resolving after my test has run, causing the test to fail.

Example Function:

```
export default function doSomething({ getData }) {

  const success = data => {
    //do stuff with the data
  }
  const handleError = () => {
    //handle the error
  }

  getData.then(response => success(response)).catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
    handleError()
  })

}
```

Example Test File:

```
import doSomething from "doSomething"

it("should log console.error if the promise is rejected", async () => {
  const getData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject("fail");
  });
  global.console.error = jest.fn();
  await doSomething({ getData });
  expect(global.console.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith("fail");
})
//fails with global.console.error has not been called
```

When I was exploring the problem, I noticed that if I add in a console.log and await that, it works.

This will pass...

```
import doSomething from "doSomething"

it("should log console.error if the promise is rejected", async () => {
  const getData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject("fail");
  });
  global.console.error = jest.fn();
  await doSomething({ getData });
  await console.log("anything here");
  expect(global.console.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith("fail");
})
```

How do I test for this correctly? Should I refactor how my `getData` function is being called? It needs to get called as soon as the `doSomething` function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why is the original test failing?**

The trick for understanding why the first test example won't pass is in digging into what the `await` operator is actually doing. From the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```
[rv] = await expression;
```

- `expression` - A Promise or any value to wait for.
- `rv` - Returns the fulfilled value of the promise, or the value itself if it's not a Promise.

In your first test the value of `expression` is the return value of the `doSomething` function. You aren't returning anything from this function, so the return value will be `undefined`. This isn't a Promise, so nothing for `await` to do, it will just return `undefined` and move on. The `expect` statement will then fail, as you haven't actually awaited the inner promise: `getData.then(...).catch(...)`.

To fix the test, without adding in the extra line, `await console.log("anything here");`, simply `return` the inner promise from the `doSomething` function, so that the `await` operator will actually operate on the Promise.

```
export default function doSomething({ getData }) {
  return getData.then(...).catch(...);
  ...
}
```

**Is this the right way to test this?**

I don't think that there is anything majorly wrong with how the `doSomething` function is written. This kind of dependency injecting usually makes functions easier to test than trying to mock out the inner workings of a function.

I would only recognise though that because you are injecting a Promise (`getData`), and resolving it within the function, you have made the `doSomething` function asynchronous (which is what made it more complicated to test).

Had you resolved the Promise and then called `doSomething` on the value it resolves to, `getData.then(doSomething).catch(handleError)`, your `doSomething` function would have been synchronous and easier to test. I would also say that writing it this way makes it much more verbose that something asynchronous is going on, whereas the original, `doSomething({ getData })`, hides that within the `doSomething` function body.

So nothing strictly incorrect, but maybe a few things to think about that might make testing easier and code more verbose. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The missing return statement was a simple but very important step. Your solution worked great.